# error datetime on PHP

Tags: php, datetime, format, str-replace

hello i need help please. mi code is error sorry for my bad englihs.

error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\aplicacion\application\views\guest\container.php on line 11`

My container.php
My intention is to get the date of creation of the blog. Be added to the url of my website. And also the name of the post

```
<?php 
                    foreach ($consulta->result() as $fila) { 
                ?>
                    <div class="post-preview">
                        <?php
                            $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YYYY-MM-DD', $fila->fecha);
                            $year = $date->format('Y',$date); 
                            $name = str_replace('','_', $fila->post);
                        ?>
                             <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>article/post/<?php echo $year ?>/<?php echo $name ?>">
```

article.php - controller

```
class article extends CI_Controller
{
public function post($year , $name)
        {

          // $fila = $this->post->getPostByName($id);
            $fila = $this->post->getPostByYearAndName($year , $name);
            if($fila == null){
                echo "ERROR";
                return;
            } 

            $data = array('titulo' => $fila->post);
            $this->load->view("guest/head" , $data);
            $data = array('app' => 'blog');
            $this->load->view("guest/nav" , $data);

            $data = array(
                'post'           => $fila->post,
                'descripcion'    => $fila->descripcion,
                'img'            =>$fila->img);
            $this->load->view("guest/header" , $data);

            $data = array('contenido' => $fila->contenido);
            $this->load->view("/guest/post" , $data);

            $this->load->view("guest/footer");
            }
```

post.php  - MODEL

```
public function getPostByYearAndName($year = '', $name = '')
        {
            $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE year(fecha) = '$year' AND post LIKE '$name'");
            return $result->row();
        }
```

Comment: 1. You receive and error. 2. Read the error. 3. Interpetate the error. 4. Search why `createFromFormat()` returns a boolean. 5. Ohh, I figured out that `$fila->fecha` is a faulty value, never mind, thanks guys!

Comment: what's the content of `$fila->fecha` ?

Comment: the $fila is the date. on DB table. an fecha. is a content in table.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y-m-d', '17-03-12');
echo $date->format('Y');
```

->

```
2017
```

if `$date` is `false` it means that your input `$fila->fecha` is not at the format `YY-MM-DD`.

If for example, your date is at the format `YYYY-MM-DD` you will have to use `'Y-m-d'` instead.

**Update:**

Just to illustrate, if the input is a date but not at the specified format, for example:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y-m-d', '2017-03-12');
echo $date->format('Y');
```

It reproduces OPs bug:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in ~/tmp/date.php:5
```

So either `$fila->fecha` is empty, not a date or not at the format `YY-MM-DD`

Comment: Yes, the code does work, I figured that out at the first glance. Perhaps you should put more emphasis on that `$fila->fecha` is a boolean.

Comment: I don't think `$fila->fecha`, I think it's a date with another format than `YY-MM-DD`. IF the date is not at the specified format in `createFromFormat `, `$date` will be `false`

Comment: Exactly, put more emphasis on that.